# Missing Some contents when export to pdf using iText

Tags: export-to-pdf

While generating report with many columns some contents had been missed in the generated report.Any idea for this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the path of the image is correct?

Comment: I fixed this issue by changing the Sheet Size in Pdf.